# Xcode storyboard not showing my custom ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

My VC inheritance is as follow:
UIViewController <- BaseVC<AModel> <- SYWelcomeViewController<WelcomeModel>

Model is a data Model, see RxSwift.
BaseVC is there to handle actions common to all VC like displaying UIActivityIndicatorView or UIAlertController.

MyWelcomeVC is my real functional ViewController, where lies the code to update the views and react to user actions.

**1st problem: Selecting the VC custom class in the storyboard**

SYWelcomeViewController doesn't appears in the storyboard custom classes drop down menu!!!!

*Whatever,*
*I forced the class by editing the XML source of the storyboard. I entered SYWelcomeViewController as the storyboard ID.
Checked the Use Storyboard ID*

**2nd problem: instantiating the custom VC:**

Executing the following code

```
let welcomeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
"SYWelcomeViewController") as! SYWelcomeViewController
```

leads to the 2 following errors:

```
 1. "Unknown class _TtC8Synappse23SYWelcomeViewController in Interface Builder file"

 2. "Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10a605758) to 'Synappse.SYWelcomeViewController'"
```

code available here: https://gist.github.com/t4ncr3d3/c8835fd19e138d1916246279bb9b782a

Any idea of what's going on?
Thanks?

Comment: Can you show these class definitions BaseVC<AModel> ,SYWelcomeViewController<WelcomeModel> ?

Comment: Is it because my BaseVC is a generic class?

Comment: No, generic class is fine. Storyboard should be able to recognise it. Is your generic class is in framework?

Comment: Edited question to add gist link

Comment: All classes are (now) in the same framework

Comment: What does the "Module" option in the custom class section in the header view say in the story board? sometimes its not re-initializes to "Current" and you need to rename and save the class name

Comment: If your ViewController is part of framework module, you should mark the class as `public`

Comment: The Base VC was part of a framework. But this wasn't satisfying. So now I included every classes in the same project same target

Comment: The Module field is empty. drop down menu is empty too.

Comment: As of today, the only way I found to make it working was to make my custom view controller a DIRECT subclass of UIViewController !!!!